# How can I add an object to an array and then update the state in react + express

Tags: reactjs, express

I am creating an app that uses the iTunes Search API and the user is able to search for an item and the website will provide information relating to they keyword/s the user inputed. I have managed to get that to work but I would like to add The feature of favoriting items. I want to push the entire object into an array and then display that array in another component. I have managed to somewhat get that done but it only displays my array when I refresh the backend in my IDE and not immediately on the page.

```
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Input from './components/InputField';


function App() {
  //These are the different state values
  const [music, setMusic] = useState('');
  const[movies, setMovies] = useState('');
  const[podcasts, setPodcasts] = useState('');
  const[audioBook, setAudioBook] = useState('');
  const[ebook, setEbooks] = useState('');
  const[tvShow, setTvShows] = useState('');
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');


  const [saveForLater, setSaveForLater] = useState([])


  return (
      <Navbar 
        music={music}
        movies={movies}
        podcasts={podcasts}
       audioBook={audioBook}
        ebook={ebook}
        tvShow={tvShow}
        saveForLater={saveForLater}
        save={save}
        setSave={setSave}
        setSaveForLater={setSaveForLater}
      />
  
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Navbar.js
//No usefull code is in this file for my issue, I have just passed props into the 
Music.js file from here

Music.js
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

const Music = ({music, save, setSave, saveForLater, setSaveForLater}) => {


  return (
    <>
    {music.results?.map((item) => (
        <Table striped bordered hover variant='dark' size='md' >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Track Name</th>
          <th>Release Date</th>
          <th>Content Advisory Rating</th>
          <th>Save</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr key={item.artistId}>
        <td>{item.trackName}</td>
              <td>{item.releaseDate}</td>
              <td>{item.contentAdvisoryRating}</td>
              <td><button type="button" onClick={function handleMusicSave(){
                let newObj = item
                setSaveForLater(saveForLater.push(newObj))
                console.log(newObj)
                console.log(saveForLater)
              }}>Save</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
   ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Music;


Saved.js

import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

const Saved = ({saveForLater}) => {
  return (
    <>
    {saveForLater.map((item) => (
        <Table striped bordered hover variant='dark' size='md' >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Release Date</th>
          <th>Artist name</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr key={item.artistId}>
        <td>{item.trackName}</td>
              <td>{item.releaseDate}</td>
              <td>{item.artistName}</td>
              <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Saved;
```

Comment: You have to use state. This won't ever work `let saveForLater = [];`

Answer (score 0):

`saveForLater` hasn't a state. Therefore, when you `push` (`saveForLater.push(newObj)`), it doesn't re-render your entire `App` component. As Konrad mentioned, you have to use state.

Update from :

```js
let saveForLater = []
```

to :

```js
const [saveForLater, setSaveForLater] = useState([]);
```

And then do the prop drilling from `App` to `Music` with `setSaveForLater`.

Advice: use the `ContextAPI` or `useReducer` for maintaning your states (I can see that you have many individual state on `App`) from ReactJS :

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree **without having to pass props down manually at every level**.

https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context

Comment: Thank you very much. I have implemented this change but I am now running into the error that my saveForLater.map is not a function. I apologize if my issues are really simple I am quite new to this and I am still trying to get to grips with a few concepts

Comment: Update `setSaveForLater(saveForLater.push(newObj))` to `setSaveForLater((current) => [...current, newObj])`